# select id and label for bootstrap autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead

I get typeahead working in my project but only for names. I am not able to process id of that particular `label` coming in autocomplete.

Bootstrap typeahead-

```
<input type="text" name="names" value="" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" />
```

**Script-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Invoice/GetNames")';

                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Json method-**

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetNames(string term)
        {
            var names = (from u in db.Contacts
                         where u.name.Contains(term)
                         select u).ToArray();
            var results = names.Select(u => u.name);

            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = results,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
```

I am selecting whole table row on match. But How do I get `Id` with label name.

**Or-**

I can select whole row at server's side, But the problem persist for filtering result for label and name.

Answer (score 0):

I used this info to also get the ID: http://fusiongrokker.com/post/heavily-customizing-a-bootstrap-typeahead (More complex... part)